# Getting progress when filling datatable

Tags: c#, database, progress-bar

I have to get amount of records that are current stored in DataTable because database server is on other location and connection is slow so fetching records sometimes can take some time and I want to know how much records is downloaded.

This is the method for filling datatable:

```
public DataTable fillMyDataTable(string sQuery)
    {

        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter;
        SqlCommandBuilder mySqlCommandBuilder;
        DataTable dataTable;

        myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sQuery, this.connection);
        mySqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240;

        dataTable = new DataTable();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        return dataTable;
    }
```

This is how i call method from above:
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

```
private void FillData()
{
        string sql = "SELECT Id, Code, Desc FROM myTable";
        dt.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(this.dt_RowChanged);
        dt = fillMyDataTable(sql);
        dt.AcceptChanges();
}

void dt_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Action == DataRowAction.Add)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Current no. of rec.: " + dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
   }
 }
```

The output should be something like 1904 of 2100 records. The problem is that dt_RowChanged event is not fired. How to do that?

**UPDATE!**
Code above works until firing dt_RowChanged event, even dt object is filled with records.

Comment: How about `dt.Rows.Count`

Answer (score 1):

To fire the event, try this. IF it does'nt use a proper delegate on the event .

```
private void FillData()
{
        string sql = "SELECT Id, Code, Desc FROM myTable";
        dt = fillMyDataTable(sql);
        DataRowChangeEventArgs args = new DataRowChangeEventArgs (dt.Rows, dt.RowState);
        dt_RowChanged(this, args);

}
```

**Update**

i just noticed you didnt declatre the event dt_RowChanged and you fired it. Perhaps thats your error after all. Do check again .

```
 dt.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(this.dt_RowChanged);
```

Comment: There is error on 4th line: Error 1 'System.Data.DataRowChangeEventArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: Pass this like i did above. IF it fails then u can use a delegate .  Or do let me know if it fails will update and test later when i am free

Comment: I've changed later declaration of event but still happens nothing. And in your example still fails on DataRowChangeEventArgs args = new DataRowChangeEventArgs (dt.Rows, dt.RowState);
dt.RowState property doesn't exist so I've changed to DataRowAction.Add but than fails on dt.Rows property

Answer (score 0):

I think i made it, this is currently my solution:

```
int iCurrentCount = 0;
int iTotalNumOfRec = 0;


iTotalNumOfRec = getNumOfRec("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable)

dt = fillMyDataTable(sql);           
int i = 0;

      while (i < iTotlNumOfRec)
      {
           DataRowChangeEventArgs args = new DataRowChangeEventArgs(dt.Rows[i], DataRowAction.Add);
           dt_RowChanged(this, args);
           ++i;
      }

     void dt_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
     {
          if (e.Action == DataRowAction.Add)
          {               
               Console.WriteLine("Current rec. no.: " + iCurrentCount.ToString());
               iCurrentCount++;
           }
      }
```

Thanks to all!

Answer (score -1):

So you want to count the number of records fetched?

```
int countFetched = dt.Rows.Count;
```

Comment: Exactly but let say that i want to count in "real time". Sometimes fetching records blocks app for a few secodns or minutes depending about server availability and how much records are fetched and when is done the app is unblocked. I want to avoid that.

Comment: you could also first count in sql like select Count(iD) FROM myTable.
That doesnt take much fetching time

Comment: already done that. I suppose that i should use background worker?

Comment: I have never worked with it myself, but you should check it out!

Comment: I've made some changes on code to fire dt_RowChanged event but evend is not fired. Don't know why.

Comment: Wow, what are you trying to do? just do 
Console.WriteLine("Current no. of rec.: " + dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
After dt = fillMyDataTable(sql);

Comment: I want to count each records added to dt (datatable). In that purpose i've added RowChanged event but this event is not fired.